# Select data from one dataframe by comparing against another dataframe in R

Tags: r

Basically I have two datasets, one is on the firm level and one is on the industry level.

The values below are contained the both datasets, although may not be in the same order. The row numbers are different as well.

```r
date <- c(1999,2000,2001...2019)
industry <- c("communication services", "utilities", "financials")

dffirm <- c(firmID, date, industry, beta, asset_ratios)
dfindustry <- c(industry, date, mean_beta, mean_asset_ratios)
```

What I want to do is to compare beta and asset ratios between the two datasets with corresponding industry and year so I can create a portfolio of firms based on certain criteria, such as:

```r
dffirm$beta < dfind$beta & dffirm$asset_ratio > dfindustry$mean_asset_ratio
```

Comment: would you want to combine the datasets based on industry and date as a unique keys? Are you hoping to do a statistical comparison?

Comment: not necessarily statistical, i'd rather not to merge the two datasets if that's what you are asking. I'm just hoping to compare the columns values between the two datasets with a couple of columns already have common values

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, I think you are looking for basic summary statistics for each of the data frames to compare. I think using `tidyverse` packages could be helpful.

**EDITED**

```
install.packages("dplyr")
install.packages("magrittr")
library("magrittr")
library("dplyr")


#some sample datasets
firm_data <- data.frame("date" = c(rep(2009,4),rep(2010,4),rep(2011,4)),
                 "firm_beta" = rnorm(12))


industry_data <- data.frame("date" = c(rep(2009,4),rep(2010,4),rep(2011,4)),
                 "industry" = rep(c("industry1","indsutry2"),6),
                 "industry_beta" = rnorm(12))


#caculate mean for column "beta" in data frame 1
industry_data2 <- industry_data %>% group_by(date) %>% 
     summarise(industry_mean_beta = mean(industry_beta))
industry_data2


#caculate mean for column "beta" in data frame 2
firm_data2 <- firm_data %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(firm_mean_beta = mean(firm_beta))
firm_data2



dc3 <- industry_data2 %>% left_join(firm_data2) %>% 
            mutate(beta_differ = case_when(
                  industry_mean_beta > firm_mean_beta ~ "industry > firm",
                  industry_mean_beta < firm_mean_beta ~ "industry > firm",
                  industry_mean_beta == firm_mean_beta ~ "industry > firm"
            ))
```

Comment: thanks for answering but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. Maybe I'm not articulating it well enough. I already have the mean beta for the industry and for the firms on an annual level. Not I want to compare the firm beta to the industry beta to determine if the firm beta satisfy the criteria I set, i.e firm_beta < industry_beta. The firm data has 18000 lines as it covers for 900 firms in 21 years, and the industry data has 220 lines as it covers for 10 industries through the same 21 years. I'm not sure the how to compare the firm level data to the matching industry level data YoY

Comment: So, for example, the goal is to compare **by year** if the beta in the firm dataset is different than beta in the industry dataset?

Comment: I have updated the results to compare by year for the firm compared to the industry dataset.